# Why does a boolean value or typeguard in a function not count as a typeguard in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to grasp a TS concept about type guarding.

Assuming I have the following situation:

```
type SomeType = string | number

const functionStr = (val: string) => { /* ... */ }
const functionNum = (val: number) => { /* ... */ }
let value: SomeType;
```

`value` can hold a value of either `string` or `number`, so when I use the above code I can do the following:

```
typeof value === 'string' ? functionStr(value) : functionNum(value)
```

Which works great. Now I was thinking: "Can I use any boolean value for this?"

```
true ? functionStr(value) : functionNum(value) // Nope TS error
```

Okay I thought, it only accepts certain things as a typeguard. So I did introduce another function into this:

```
const typeGuard = (val: SomeType) => typeof value === 'string'

typeGuard(value) ? functionStr(value) : functionNum(value) // Nope also error, but why?
```

But this also errors in TS. I am wondering why and what kind of typeguard would work?

Comment: Because your function _isn't_ a type guard, it doesn't return a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates). And `true` on its own obviously gives the compiler no information about the type of `value`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks, so the compile needs the `typeof` immediately next to it, and when it is inside a function call it won't work either?

Comment: `typeof value === 'string'` gives the compiler information, `true` does not (like anyone else reading the code, it's left with the question: _what's_ true?) Likewise a function returning type `val is string` gives the compiler information, `boolean` does not.

Comment: It will work inside a function if you properly declare it as a type predicate

Comment: So assuming I have a function that typeguards, I need to do it via `val is string` as the return value, no other way around this?

Comment: If your function doesn't return a type predicate, again, it is **not** a type guard (at least as far as the compiler is concerned, whether you consider it one or not). You could still do e.g. `typeGuard(value) ? functionStr(value as string) : functionNum(value as number)` ([playground](https://tsplay.dev/mL8Lem)).

Comment: @jonrsharpe okay I see, I was wondering whether it is always necessary to set a type predicate as the return of that function, or whether the compiler knows other ways around this? Could you kindly formulate an answer? I think this would be helpful not only to me.